# Find the $2011^{th}$ term of the sequence $2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the $2011^{th}$ term of the sequence $2,3,5,6,7,8,10,11,...$
>   (a) $2056$
>   (b) $2011$
>   (c) $2013$
>   (d) $2060$

**My Approach:**
Let $2,3,5,6,7,8$ be one set of numbers.
In every 6 terms we reach 8 terms forward. From 1 to 9, 6 terms are present but the jump is of 8.
$2011/6=335+1/6$.
Hence 335 such whole sets and 1st term of the 336th set would give us the 2011th term.
335 full sets starting from 1, each of a jump 8 will reach $2+(335)(8)=2682$. Now the first term of the next set is $2683$.

But this doesn't match with any of the options given. Have I identified the sequence wrongly or is there a flaw in my logic?

Comment: I think in this sequence are missing all squares: $1=1^2$, $4=2^2$, $9=3^2$.

Comment: Relevant squares: $44^2 =1936$, $45^2 = 2025$ and $46^2 = 2116$.

Comment: Your logic is fine; there is an inherent flaw in all questions of this kind. Every sequence can be continued in infinitely many different ways, and we can't tell one from another using only a finite fragment. Essentially, this is an exercise of the type _"guess what I was thinking"_, and Jimmy's answer looks quite probably right.

Comment: My first post using colors:$${\color{red}1},2,3,{\color{red}4},5,6,7,8,{\color{red}9},10,11,\ldots$$

Comment: we need to solve $m-\text{floor}\left(\sqrt{m}\right)=2011$.

Comment: Clearly they want the sequence to be all the non-squares and you missed that and therefore have gotten the sequence "wrong".  However they are the ones who are wrong in assuming that if the list the first several terms of a sequence is good enough to define the sequence.  Unless the rules or definition of a sequence is given, a sequence can be *anything*-- not just the one it's "supposed" to be.  I can not begin to tell you how *DISGUSTED* I get at presumptuous questions like this, especially as a class.  This question has no answer.  But the people who wrote it think it does.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** One way to continue this sequence is to eliminate all squares: $$1=1^2, \quad 4=2^2, \quad 9=3^2, \quad \dots,\quad 45^2=2025$$

Answer (score 7):

If $a_n$ is the given sequence then $a_n-n=$ the number of squares less than or equal to $a_n$ which equals $\left\lfloor \sqrt{a_n}\right\rfloor $

Therefore we need to solve for $m$

$$m-\left\lfloor \sqrt{m}\right\rfloor =2011$$

This leads to the inequalities

$$2010<m-\sqrt{m}\leq 2011$$

and so

$$2055.34<m\leq 2056.35$$

and

$$m=2056$$

Comment: May I know how did you get the first equation in your answer?

Comment: @Intellex Thank you for your question. I added something that I hope will clarify my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just skipping the squares leads us to **2056**. So the answer to the question is 
**(a) 2056**

Answer (score 1):

Compare the two sequences:
$$\color{red}1,2,3,\color{red}{2^2},5,6,7,8,\color{red}{3^2},10,...,\underbrace{\color{red}{44^2}}_{1936},1937,1938,...,2010,\color{blue}{2011},2012,...,\underbrace{\color{green}{45^2}}_{2025},...,\underbrace{\color{green}{46^2}}_{2116},...\\
2,3,5,6,7,8,10,...,2011,\underbrace{2012}_{\color{red}1},\underbrace{2013}_{\color{red}{2^2}},\underbrace{2014}_{\color{red}{3^2}},...,\underbrace{2055}_{\color{red}{44^2}},\underbrace{2056}_{\color{green}{45^2}}\\
\color{blue}{2011}+\color{green}{45}=2056.$$
Note: $2011<\color{green}{2025=45^2}<2011+\color{red}{44}<\color{green}{2116=46^2}$, therefore $2025=\color{green}{45^2}$ is skipped too.

Comment: I think you have made an addition mistake. 2011+44=2055 right?

Comment: @Intellex, good catch, fixed it, thank you.

Comment: That's fine...……..

Comment: the idea was to move all those squares after the term $\color{blue}{2011}$. I oversaw the fact that the square number $45^2$ was within this range, so added $1$ for it.